# Distribution rolling two dice

Tags: probability-distributions

Let's suppose we are considering the experiment of rolling two dice
and X is the random variable that tracks the number of one die and Y the
number of the other die.

--> What are the distributions of X (and Y) ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are confused about? For example, do you know the probability of getting a 1 on the first die?

Comment: To understand why your question was downvoted, you can refer to [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  In fact, you can also refer to [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (I presume) the dice are uncorollated, i.e., are independent of one another, we obtain that  $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables that attain the values $1$ until $6$ with probability $1/6$ (assuming that the dice are fair and have $6$ faces).

**Edit based on comment:**

In other words, we have
$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\mathbb P(Y=k)=\frac16,\quad k\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$$
Observe, for example, that
$$\sum_{k=1}^6\mathbb P(X=k)=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^6\{X=k\}\right)=\mathbb P(X\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})=1.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do I write down the distributions? X = {1, 2, ..., 6} or how would you do this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, now it's clear. :)

Comment: I've got one last question: the probability that X > 3 knowing that Y = 2 is 1/2, right?